# Who has held the largest number of different UK Cabinet positions?

Tags: united-kingdom, statistics, cabinet

On June 26th, [Sajid Javid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sajid_Javid) replaced Matt Hancock as the Secretary of State for Health and Social Care after the latter's [resignation](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-57625508). This is Javid's sixth cabinet-level position within seven years:

| **Cabinet Position** | **Ministry** | **Dates** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Secretary of State for Culture, Media and Sport | First Cameron Ministry | 2014–15 |
| Secretary of State for Business, Innovation and Skills | Second Cameron Ministry | 2015–16 |
| Secretary of State for Communities and Local Government | First May Ministry | 2016–18 |
| Home Secretary | Second May Ministry | 2018–19 |
| Chancellor of the Exchequer | First Johnson Ministry | 2019–20 |
| Secretary of State for Health and Social Care | Second Johnson Ministry | 2021– |

This is definitely quite a CV, but is this a record? Has anyone ever held more than six different cabinet-level positions? If so, what about in such a short space of time?

As the list of cabinet-level positions changes over time, let's consider the state of the office when it was held by the individual in question.

Comment: Is this question restricted to the UK, or are cabinet members from other governments eligible too ?

Comment: @Evargalo I'm really interested in the UK for this question; doesn't seem fair to compare apples to oranges. Could make an interesting separate question though!

Comment: @Evargalo Even more interesting would be if anyone has been a cabinet member in more than one country?  Or for that matter any other elected/appointed government official in more than one country.  (Other than ambassadors, they obviously get shuffled around a bit.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman see [Have any politicians been elected to the government of two different countries during their career?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/25610) :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, to begin with a classic, [Winston Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) was:

- President of the Board of Trade (1908-1910),
- Home Secretary (1910-1911),
- First Lord of the Admiralty (1911-1915),
- [Chancellor of the Duchy of Lancaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancellor_of_the_Duchy_of_Lancaster), i.e. minister without portfolio (1915)
- Minister of Munitions (1917-1919),
- Secretary of State for War (1919-1921), concurrently with
- Secretary of State for Air (1919-1921),
- Secretary of State for the Colonies (1921-1922),
- Chancellor of the Exchequer (1924-1929),
- First Lord of the Admiralty (again), (1939-1940),
- Prime Minister (1940-1945),
- Prime Minister (again) (1951-1955)

which gives a grand total of 12 (with dupes) or 10 (without dupes).

Answer (score 10):

I haven't been able to discover anyone with a more varied collection of cabinet posts than Churchill, but in more recent years, [John Reid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Reid,_Baron_Reid_of_Cardowan), now Baron Reid, held eight Cabinet-level positions during Tony Blair's reign as Prime Minister - all within a seven-year period.

| **Cabinet Position** | **Ministry** | **Dates** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Secretary of State for Scotland | First Blair Ministry | 1999–2001 |
| Secretary of State for Northern Ireland | First Blair Ministry | 2001–02 |
| Minister Without Portfolio | Second Blair Ministry | 2002–03 |
| Leader of the House of Commons | Second Blair Ministry | 2003 |
| Lord President of the Council | Second Blair Ministry | 2003 |
| Secretary of State for Health | Second Blair Ministry | 2003–05 |
| Secretary of State for Defence | Third Blair Ministry | 2005–06 |
| Home Secretary | Third Blair Ministry | 2006–07 |